# CURL and Postman returning two different results for the same request

Tags: xml, curl, soap, postman

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request to a SOAP server. The request works fine with Postman, but fails with curl. This is an authentication request and so Postman response is a 200 while curl response is a 401.

Curl request:

```
curl -X POST 
-H "SOAPAction:urn:NETGEAR-ROUTER:service:DeviceConfig:1#SOAPLogin" 
-H "cache-control: 'no-cache'" 
-H "user-agent: 'node-test'" 
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
-H "connection: 'Keep-Alive'" 
http://routerlogin.net:5000/soap/server_sa/ 
-d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8'?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:v='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <v:Header>
    <SessionID>********</SessionID>
  </v:Header>
  <v:Body>
    <M1:SOAPLogin xmlns:M1='urn:NETGEAR-ROUTER:service:DeviceConfig:1'>
      <Username>******</Username>
      <Password>******</Password>
    </M1:SOAPLogin>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>"
```

Postman request is just a copy of the above request. I receive the below response for postman:

```
<soap-env:Body>
   <m:SOAPLoginResponse xmlns:m="urn:NETGEAR-ROUTER:service:DeviceConfig:1">
   </m:SOAPLoginResponse>
  <ResponseCode>000</ResponseCode>
</soap-env:Body>
```

While I recieve the below for curl:

```
<soap-env:Envelope
        xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        soap-env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        >
<soap-env:Body>
    <ResponseCode>401</ResponseCode>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

-H 'SOAPAction:"urn:NETGEAR-ROUTER:service:DeviceConfig:1#SOAPLogin"'